# Unity XR Interaction Toolkit multiple cameras shows mirrored pixelated mess

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusquest

New to unity so hoping this is a dumb / quick fix.

I'm using XR Interaction Toolkit's XR Origin camera (device-based if it matters) and want to add a second camera to overlay my UI elements so the canvases appear on top of walls / elements instead of intersecting and being hidden by them.

I've duplicated my main camera and removed all scripts except the main camera one, set it as a child to the previous main camera, and adjusted the culling masks to be UI-only and Everything-but-UI. I've also set the depth of the ui camera to be higher than the main camera, and set `Clear Flags` to `Depth only`. My UI elements are in the correct layer and the camera of the canvas is the child UI camera.

The result is a disaster. When I click the button to bring up my UI overlay, me view becomes a 360 pixelated block of tiny mirrored rectangles.

Any help would be appreciated, or workarounds not using 2 cameras.

Thanks all

[image: UI camera settings][image: Main camera settings]

[image: pixelated mess]